# Scheduling the most intervals rather than scheduling the most tasks

Tags: algorithm

Interval scheduling tends to consider how to schedule the greatest number of tasks, rather than have as much time as possible be scheduled. Any thoughts on how to modify the typical greedy algorithm to optimize for time usage rather than # of tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an O(nlog n) dynamic programming algorithm:

Suppose there are n tasks, beginning at times b(j) and ending at times e(j) for 1 <= j <= n.  Let f(x) be the greatest amount of time that can be scheduled (used) **under the constraint that no scheduled task uses any time after time x.**  (x need not be integer.)  We will compute f(max(e(j))), where the maximum is taken over all tasks: this will be the final answer.

Instead of recording the values of f() in an array so that f(x) is given by the xth element of the array, we will record only an array of pairs (x, y), in increasing order of x, but allowing gaps in the x values.  Call this array S.  There will be one (x, y) pair in S for each best ("fullest") solution whose last used interval of time ends *exactly* at time x, and uses y units of time in total.  To find f(x), we will binary search in this array of pairs to find the pair (x', y) with x' <= x but as large as possible.  Intuitively, this means that when looking for the best solution that uses no time after x, if there is no best solution that uses time "right up to" time x, then we "fall back" to the best solution that ends before then.

1. Sort all n tasks by their end time.
2. For j from 1 to n:

   - Idea: Try adding task j to the best schedule that can accommodate it, namely f(b(j)).  We will compare this schedule to f(e(j)) to see whether it is better to include task j or not.  Calculating f(b(j)) requires a binary search through S, but f(e(j)) can be calculated in constant time because it will always be the rightmost pair in S.
   - If f(b(j)) + e(j) - b(j) > f(e(j)) then remove any trailing pairs (e(j), y) in S and append (e(j), f(b(j)) + e(j) - b(j)) to S.
3. Return the final element of S, which corresponds to f(max(e(j))).

To actually recover a schedule, a third element can be added to each of the pairs in the array S to record the identity of the rightmost task just added.  Then once the algorithm above has run, just trace back through the array S starting from the end, at each step binary-searching for the fullest solution that ends at or before b(j), where j was the task reported in the previous step.